# How should i map the relationship between many users and department

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have the following entities

`Department` has many `Users` and users have many `Records`.

Now i want that  users can see all records of same `department`.

I am confused do i need to make relation ship between `Department` and `Records` or it can be traversed through users

Comment: And your goal is? What is the problem? "Now all users can see all records of same department" so do you want it like that or what?

Comment: you should must mention what you want, i can't understand..

Comment: @Hardy i was thinking it may be easier to query for records in same department if i have that relation

Comment: Ok, now it's clearer. See @Lie Ryan answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOINS` are efficient then sub-queries.

This is what you can try using `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM records AS r
INNER JOIN
users AS u ON (r.user_id = u.user_id)
WHERE u.department_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM Records WHERE user_id IN (SELECT User.id FROM User WHERE department_id = 123)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a 1-n relation from `department` to `users` and a 1-n relation from `users` to `records`. Then you know which department a record belongs to by looking up which department the user belongs to that this record is assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

If user has `id_department` and record has `id_user` then you can get all records that relates to certain department.

Answer (score 0):

**sample code:**

```
SELECT a.batsman_id,a.matchs,a.hundreds,b.country_type, c.player_name
FROM batsman a  INNER JOIN countrycode b ON a.country_code=b.country_code
        INNER JOIN players c ON a.player_id=c.player_id
        ORDER BY a.batsman_id;
```

**screen shots:**

[image: countrycode]

[image: players]

[image: batsman]

[image: output]